Determine which button was clicked after adding multiple buttons programmatically C#
I have a text file with a few lines of data, each line containing 2 pieces of data. I split the data with a # delimiter and assign the first piece of each line to a button name and create a button. The second piece of data will be used later (it's just an inputted path, you can see that in the code lol) but is not relevant to this question.
As of right now, I have a TableLayoutPanel with 3 columns and 4 rows. Depending on the data in the file, a button will be placed in a row&column accordingly.
Lets say the file I'm reading from has 4 lines of data, then 4 buttons will be created, 3 on the first row, one on the second row.
Here's my code:
        private void GetAllPaths()
        {

            int count = 0;
            StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader("app-paths.txt");
            string line = inFile.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                string[] temp = line.Split("#");

                CreateButton(temp[0], temp[1]);
                count++;

                line = inFile.ReadLine();
            }
            inFile.Close();

            if (count > 0)
            {
                label1.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void CreateButton(string appName, string appPath)
        { 
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = Button, Width = 150, Height = 100, BackColor = Color.SlateBlue, Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.5f, FontStyle.Bold), Dock = DockStyle.Fill, AutoSize = true }, 0, 0);
        } 

And here is my button click event:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string appName = textBox1.Text;
    string appPath = textBox2.Text;

    if (appName == "" || appPath == "")
    {
        label6.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        label6.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = false;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";

        AddNewPath(appName, appPath);
        CreateButton(appName, appPath);
    }
}

Because each button is created programmatically, how can I tell which created button is clicked? Am I able to get the name or some type of ID/Key for each button?

What does your button click event look like?

@GHDevOps I just updated my question to include my click event. The AddNewPath method is a simple open file, write to file, close to file.

If you do Button btn = sender as Button; then btn should have any property you set when you create that new button. Then you can do a switch on that property. You'll probably have to use some type of index which will represent each line in the layout.

@GHDevOps That logic makes sense, thank you!

In your CreateButton method, you don't hook up any event listeners to the button, such as button1_Click when the Click event fires.
